# XSD Validation Error in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I'm trying to validate my XML files from given XSD file with the following code,

```
        Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(fXmlFile);
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
        .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("presentation.xsd"));
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        try {
            validator.validate(xmlFile);
            System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is valid");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
            System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

And I uploaded my XSD file to here to show you: http://orhancanceylan.com/stack/presentation.xsd

But when I run my code, I get this error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'maxOccurs' cannot appear in element 'element'.
```

What's the problem, how should I solve it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an error in your schema, global presentation element cannot have constraints ( maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"), you'd need to remove them (it does not make sense to have min/max for global elements, those constraints makes sense in context of other elements).
More on this in XSD Primer: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/#Globals

Comment: +1 - the reason for this restriction is becaz any global element is a potential root element in the instance document